# Is this the proper way to integrate normalization?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, normalization

I'm trying to wrap my head around normalization.
Is this the proper way to create a database with this data? How much more effective is it to use a foreign key instead of just repeating AAPL for example?

This would be the company profile, with foreign key for each company

[image: This is the Company table]

This is the table which holds all the data. A few columns shown for example but would have another 30 or so columns. Each company would have 20 years of data or so. CompanyID links to foreign key of Company Profile table.
[image]

Thanks! Any tips greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three good reasons for normalizing your tables.

1. It minimizes redundancy of the data. In your example AAPL wouldn't need to be repeated for every record it belongs to in the main data table. It only exists in one record in the CompanyProfile table.
2. As you see, instead the CompanyID in your main data table is repeated, and that's ok, it's much lighter weight to repeat an integer than the string of text such as AAPL. So there's a performance gain here.
3. If you didn't normalize, but instead repeatedly stored the CompanyName in the main data table, and the Company changed it's name one day then you'd have to update every row in the main data table to fix the CompanyName. But normalizing it into its own table means you'd only have to change the CompanyName in one row. Not only is this much better from a maintenance standpoint, it's also a lot more efficient.

*Also just a sidenote, but your CompanyProfile table likely doesn't need that ForeignKey column. It has a PrimaryKey column which is unique within itself (and unrelated to the PrimaryKey column in your main data table). You can have your foreign key relationship from the main data table on CompanyId to the PrimaryKey column of CompanyProfile (as is usually how people design their tables).

Answer (score 1):

In your second table, it seems like `(company_id, fiscal_year)` would be unique, hence viable as the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Then get rid of `id`.

If you can use tickers throughout, `"AAPL"` seems like a reasonable `PRIMARY KEY`.  Again, toss `id`.  I don't know what you mean by the column "foreign key" -- you should link to the PK.  (The 'weight' of a `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` and a `VARCHAR(10) CHARSET ascii` is probably not as big a deal as JD suggests -- at least if you have only thousands of companies, not millions.)

`company_id`, whether it looks like `1` or `AAPL` will be repeated a lot of places.  But in one table it will show up exactly once -- your first table.

Thousands of rows (hundreds of companies times 20 years) with 30 columns -- fine.  Just don't have an "array" of stuff spread across columns.

Company names and tickers rarely change.  Long ago, "International Business Machines" changed to "IBM".  The ticker "AOL" changed to "TRW".  Mergers happen.  Google becomes part of Alphabet.  Etc, etc.  Each cause some kind of hiccup.  Normalization decreases the hassles; you decide where the cutoff is -- among speed/space/hassle/etc.